# Booting into ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, boot

When I first installed ubuntu 12.10 the boot loaded quickly without going through a long loaded screen. Now I get the long screen of all the drivers and recovery before it finally boots. Is there a way to get it back to the short boot screen?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way you can try to solved the problem is open or search startup applications preferences. Unchecked and disable unnecessary startup app.

[image].

It's quite general and it has lot of possibilities and reason for slow boot up. This usually happen to me and it help. Maybe it help you too.